# vba excel macro (cell contains specific text)

Tags: vba

macro is searching A column for cells with specific text and writes another text to another cell in all next rows until it finds next A cell with specific text and does the same.
**ex**

```
A1 contains text "(1)" then write text "a" in C2,C3,C4.... until it finds
A10 contains text "(16)" then write text "b" in C11,C12,..... until it finds
A24 contains text "(19)" th[enter image description here][1]en write "c" in C25,C26 ...
```

All the other cells between cells that contain text contain numbers

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm unsure what the question is?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to show some programming effort to solve the problem before seeking help.

Answer (score 0):

you can go like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim iArea As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim texts As Variant

    texts = Array("a", "b", "c") '<--| array containing your "texts", be sure therer are at least as much elements as cells with "('number')" in column A

    With Worksheets("mySheet") '<--| change "mySheet" to your actual worksheet with data name
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "A" cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
            With .Resize(.Rows.count + 1)
                .Cells(.Rows.count).Value = "number : (0)" '<--| add "dummy" "specific" text. it'll be removed by the end of the macro
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=*(*)*" '<--| filter it with "*(*)*" string
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any filtered cell found
                    Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| set the range corresponding filtered cells
                    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
                    With rng '<--| reference filtered cells
                        For iArea = 1 To .Areas.count - 1 '<--| loop through them (each filtered cell is an 'Area') excluding last ("dummy") one
                            .Parent.Range(.Areas(iArea).Cells(2, 3), .Areas(iArea + 1).Cells(1, 3).Offset(-1)).Value = texts(iArea - 1) 'fill column "C" (third from referenced cell in column A) with 'texts' element corresponding to current area
                        Next iArea
                    End With
                End If
               .Cells(.Rows.count).ClearContents '<--| clear add "dummy" "specific" text
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```